# How to fix a weird linux kernel module build problem on raspbian that works fine on x64 ubuntu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, raspbian, kernel-module

I ran into this problem and figured it out but it took me a while because it wasn't obvious, so I thought I'd post here to help out if anybody else has this problem.

I have a linux kernel module that I build on x86 and on a bunch of raspberry pis running raspian.

the build works fine on x64 ubuntu and it works fine when I run make from the command line on the raspberry pis.

But I have a build script to automate all the things that have to build and only in that case was it failing on the raspians.

the error I was getting was:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.75-v7+' Makefile:614: arch/armv7l/Makefile: No such file or directory make[1]:
*** No rule to make target 'arch/armv7l/Makefile'.  Stop. make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.75-v7+'
```

Looked fine to me, and it worked fine from the command line just not my build script.
See below for the solution.

Comment: Help with the script we never seen and find out (magically?) that it is missed `ARCH` variable/parameter which causes the problem? No, this is not how Stack Overflow works. Note, that while self-answered questions are allowed on Stack Overflow, such questions should fit to the same requirements as normal ones.

Comment: I dunno, stackoverflow suggested to me that I post the question and answer it myself for the benefit of others. The lesson learned here is that you can't set the "ARCH" environment variable when building a kernel module or it will mess up the build process. There is no documentation to that effect that I could find, so I had to learn this lesson the hard way by figuring it out for myself. So my goal in asking and answering this question was to pass on this nugget of information so others will not have to suffer as I have. A wise old man once said "If you do not like what you see, don't look."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few raspberry pis that build different architectures so in my build script I had added

export ARCH=`uname -m`

and I'd append that to the end of the build result filename.

It turns out that something about the kernel module build where make forks make -C again uses the ARCH environment variable, which my script was changing unexpectedly.

I was confused by the message "*** No rule to make target 'arch/armv7l/Makefile'" because that looks legit, but apparently that was being derived from the incorrect ARCH environment variable.

I change the name of the ARCH variable in the script and it all started working again.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Hey there, if this solved your problem you can accept your own answer. That way your post can be marked as solved.